# How to clean reinstall Windows 10 without erasing Linux?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, multi-boot, reinstall

My windows 10 PC has been acting up lately, it doesn't accept any updates no matter what so I want to give it a clean reinstall because not even recovery upgrade and that stuff worked, I wanna reinstall it right from a new USB.

I have Linux Mint on the other partition and I wanna know how to reinstall windows 10 without erasing that.

EDIT: I will first try what John suggested, but I doubt that will work, although I do want the easier way

Comment: Don't install Windows 10 on the partition that has Linux Mint. What more do you need?

Comment: @NasirRiley Windows creates a bunch of partitions. What I would do is use GParted and delete all Windows partitions. Then in the windows installer you will have the option to select the free space (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: If you select the same partition, that Windows is currently installed on, it won't touch the partition Linux is installed on

Comment: To be safe, make a disk image *before* reinstallation. If Mint is damaged (and, yes, I've had that happen, despite other's protests otherwise), you can easily revert to where you were.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Windows doesn't do anything with the partitions that exist unless one chooses to do so. Take it from someone who has been installing Windows since the mid 90's on home computers and on enterprise workstations and servers for over a decade. There are plenty of Youtube videos that will walk one through how to do it whether it's on a blank disk or on a system that has other operating systems already installed.

Comment: You can also run a Windows 10 Repair from the Media Creation link and use the option to Keep Nothing. That is very close to a fresh install, works, and uses the existing Windows 10 partitions.

Comment: Just don't remove the EFI system partition if it is shared by both Windows and Linux. Only remove the `EFI/Microsoft` directory (It would probably be `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft` or `/boot/EFI/Microsoft`.) You will probably need to re-install grub (or recover its MBR boot code if backed up) anyway if you are on BIOS / CSM.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you still have your Linux installation media, and if you don’t, make it again. Then, note which partition is Linux and which is Windows. Now, boot into your windows installation media, and SELECT THE PARTITION THAT WINDOWS WAS PREVIOUSLY INSTALLED ON. Do not select any other partition. After you are done installing windows, you can boot into your Linux installation media and reinstall grub. Hope this helps

Comment: So I tried a clean install with Media Creation Tool, chose to keep nothing since I wanted a fresh start on Windows 10, anyway, and in the middle of installing windows 10 on the blue screen at about 60%, it just said Windows 10 installation failed. Nope.

Comment: Huh. I’ve had problems with windows installation media in the past. You should try to use a different USB drive, or a dual layer dvd if you have one, as dvds are extremely reliable, at least from what I’ve found